# CakePHP 2.8 does not show the images in the plug-in

Tags: image, cakephp, plugins

I think so. This happen to me, if I have an image under Plugin path,
by example

```
/app/Plugin/Plugin_name/webroot/img/img_name.png
```

The framework doesn't show it. Also display an error, like 'image not readble, contains error'

Doesn't happen for js or css files.

It seem like the image is treated as a text,  however i see the mime type is image/png

This doesn't happen with my previous version 2.4.5

Comment: Please show us, the code for image you are using..

Comment: I have moved al my images on _app/webroot_.
But the same happen to me, by example, in the **debugkit** plugin version 2.2.6, in the view _/app/Plugin/DebugKit/View/Elements/debug_toolbar.ctp_ at the line  29

`echo $this->Html->image('/debug_kit/img/cake.icon.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP')); `
         
With the image under the plugin webroot image path:
_/app/Plugin/DebugKit/webroot/img/cake.icon.png_

@Confused

Comment: You need to ensure that URL rewriting is enabled in your webserver as described on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Also, how do you include/display the image?